# Can I avoid storing a Jar file in my repository for unit testing with travis-ci?

Tags: java, unit-testing, travis-ci

If I have a repository setup for unit testing with [travis-ci](http://travis-ci.org/) from what I can tell I have to include the JUnit `.jar` files within the repo so that travis-ci can find them.

Is there a way to avoid storing the .jar files for JUnit itself?

**EDIT** This is the repository: https://github.com/krisives/jbloomer

Answer (score 1):

Travis CI have a page on [Building a Java project](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java). That page lists three ways they support building Java projects: Maven, Gradle and Ant. Maven and Gradle have support for dependency management, but Ant does not. Your project should switch to Maven/Gradle, introduce a dependency manager (such as [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)), or hand-roll a half-baked, custom solution (i.e. you can call [whatever Ant target you want](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java#Dependency-Management)). Maven, Gradle or Ivy would be preferred solutions (IMO).

Comment: Thanks. I chose Ant because I thought it would be the most supported by the CI tools =(

Comment: You can still use Ant with Ivy.